# How do I find the normal vector at point $p$ on a cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

How do I find the normal vector at point $p$ on a cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$?
I would find this normal vector on point $p$ with any graphic of a function like $(-z_x,-z_y,1)$, but in this case I have no $z$ in my definition of the function. So what do I do heard? I have some point $(x,y,z)$ on the cylinder. I would think that the normal vector would be the same as $(x,y)$ on a circle. Trouble is, I forgot how to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, you'll have $N(x,y,z) = (x,y,0)$. If you really want to do calculations with a parametrization, you can write ${\bf x}\colon ]0,2\pi[ \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$, $${\bf x}(u,v) = (\cos u, \sin u, v),$$and look at $$N({\bf x}(u,v))=\frac{\partial {\bf x}}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial {\bf x}}{\partial v}(u,v) = (\cos u, \sin u, 0),$$which happens to be already a unit vector.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the cylinder is independent of $z$: the surface is invariant along the $z$-axis. Then its axis is the $z$-axis. A normal vector must have its 3rd coordinate equal to zero. At a point $(x,y)$, its expression is $(x,y,0)$. It is normalized because of the cylinder equation.

Answer (score 0):

The unit cylinder $S$ is $f^{-1}(0)$, where $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$. A unit normal to it is then:

$$N = \frac1{\|\nabla f \|} \nabla f$$

Wee have $\nabla f = (2x,2y,0)$, so $\| \nabla f \| = 2$ (because we evaluate it at the points of $S$). Thus: $N = (x,y,0)$.